# Oracle json_object missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-apex

Why does the below sql give an error. I tried this in apex.oracle.com .
The absent on null works when its on the last key column but not on the first.
How can I implement absent on null if its not the last key .

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
     (KEY 'employee_name' VALUE e.ename ABSENT ON NULL,
     KEY 'commission' VALUE e.comm
     --ABSENT ON NULL
   ) AS employees
FROM   emp e
WHERE  e.deptno = 10;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`absent on null` affects *everything*, not just one key column.

```
SQL> with emp (ename, comm) as
  2    (select 'Little', 20   from dual union all  -- everything is here
  3     select 'Foot'  , null from dual union all  -- COMM is absent
  4     select null    , 50   from dual union all  -- ENAME is absent
  5     select null    , null from dual            -- both are absent
  6  )
  7  SELECT JSON_OBJECT
  8       (KEY 'employee_name' VALUE e.ename,
  9        KEY 'commission'    VALUE e.comm
 10        --
 11        ABSENT ON NULL
 12       ) AS employees
 13  FROM emp e;

EMPLOYEES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"employee_name":"Little","commission":20}   -- everything is here
{"employee_name":"Foot"}                     -- COMM is absent
{"commission":50}                            -- ENAME is absent
{}                                           -- both are absent

SQL>
```